# Nestjs - Manually instantiate a class with dependencies on useFactory

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

suppose I have two classes like this

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.DEFAULT })
class Service {
    
    constructor() {}
    // ...
}

@Injectable()
class OtherService {
    param: T;

    constructor(readonly service: Service, param: T) {}

    // ... 
}
```

And I'm triying to dinamically instantiate the last class using a factory

```
const otherServiceFactory = {
    provide: "TOKEN",
    scope: Scope.Request,
    useFactory: (req: Request) => {
        const param = req.headers["foo"];
        return new OtherService(/* ts expects an instance of Service here */ , param)
    },
    inject: [REQUEST]
}
```

As the comment said, at the moment of creating the instance ts expects, correctly, an instance of `Service`. The problem is I rather not mess up with the DI tree, so I don't want to instantiate `Service`. I was able to hack this around by setting the param later instead of asking in the constructor, so I don't need the factory anymore, but feels pretty sub-optimal. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Service` to the `inject` array, and get the instance of `Service` that Nest creates, then pass it to `OtherService` so that you have everything required to create the class.

```js
const otherServiceFactory = {
    provide: "TOKEN",
    scope: Scope.Request,
    useFactory: (req: Request, service: Service) => {
        const param = req.headers["foo"];
        return new OtherServiceservice, param)
    },
    inject: [REQUEST, Service]
}
```